# Find a non zero element $z\in \mathbb Z_{100}$ such that $yz = 0_{R}$ and $zy = 0_{R}$ where $y =\overline{ 14}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

> Find a non zero element $z\in \mathbb Z_{100}$ such that $yz = 0_{R}$ and $zy = 0_{R}$ where $y =\overline{ 14}$

For this I have found such an element to be $\overline{50}$ since $\overline{14}*\overline{50} = \bar{0}$. Am I doing this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In fact, you found the only answer to the problem, since $14$ is divisible by $2$ but not by $2^2$ or $5$ (and $100=2^2\cdot 5^2$).

Comment: Thanks for editing my question.

Comment: Thanks again. I was confused.

Comment: Hint: $\ 100\mid 14z\iff 50\mid 7z\iff 50\mid z\,$ by Euclid's Lemma and $\,(50,7)=1\ \ $

Comment: Isn't multiplication commutative in $Z_{100}$?

Answer (score 1):

As your computation shows, $\overline{50}$ is a solution. What follows is a proof that it is the only solution. Alternatively, you may consider the following as a method to find such a solution if it can't be found by inspection.

---

As $\mathbb{Z}_{100}$ is a commutative ring, $yz = 0$ if and only if $zy = 0$, so it is enough to check one of these two conditions.

Suppose $z \in \mathbb{Z}_{100}$ satisfies $\overline{14}z = 0$, then $z = \overline{k}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ($k$ is unique up to adding a multiple of $100$). Then $0= \overline{14}z = \overline{14k}$, so $14k \equiv0 \pmod{100}$, that is $100 \mid 14k$, which is equivalent to $50 \mid k$. Therefore $k = 50l$ for some integer $l$. If $l$ is even, $z = \overline{k} = 0$; if $l$ is odd, $z = \overline{k} = \overline{50}$.

So the only non-zero element $z$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{100}$ with $\overline{14}z = 0$ is $z = \overline{50}$.